magic numbers in *.d folders
I'm wondering, what is the meaning of magic numbers in filenames in configuration folders? For example, 50 in
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades or 52 in
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/52unattended-upgrades-local. I think its somehow related with order of parsing these files in folder?

See also my answer to "Why is "50-cloud-init.conf" created?"

As far as I know there isn't a standard describing this, but you are right, it's for ordering of the configuration files.
Whether the order actually means something depends on the tool/daemon using these config files, but in general the tools will read the config files in order. For example with udev rules you can create your custom rule file with name like 99-custom.rules to explicitly override something set by the system rule from for example 60-block.rules and because udev parses the files in alphabetical order your 99 rule will be parsed after the 60 rule overwriting udev properties etc.
